# Area surrounded by a curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would need help to calculate the area surrounded by a curve.
The curve is given with the following polar coordinates:

[image]

I know we need need to integrate with respect to r and theta but am stuck with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider that area as the sum of two integrals:

$$\int_{C}r ~ dr ~d\theta = \int_{C_1}r ~ dr ~d\theta + \int_{C_2} r ~ dr ~d\theta = 2 \int_{C_1} r ~dr ~d\theta$$

Where $C_1$ is the part of the curve which has a positive $x$ coordinate. For this part of the curve $\theta$ varies in the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]$. So the integral that has to be solved is:

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} d \theta \int_0^{2 \sqrt{cos(2 \theta)}} r ~dr = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} cos(2 \theta)  ~ d \theta $$

The result of this integral is:

$$\left. sin(x)cos(x) \right|_{- \frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} = 1$$

So the total area enclosed by the curve is equal to 2.